# Set the color steps in the GnuPlot color bar

Tags: gnuplot, colorbar

I would like to have a color bar divided into 5 colors. One color from 0 to 20, another until 40, and so on until 100.

What I have done so far is:

```
set palette maxcolors 5
```

But this doesn't set the boundries of each color in the colorbar

Do you have suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

To avoid setting the boundaries manually, you're on the right track.  What might help is to set the color bar's range:

```
set cbrange [0:100]
```

That way the palette will be divided into 5 colors just between 0 and 100, instead of having the limits determined by the data/function being plotted.

Comment: But actualy what I need is dynamically set. My range will go to 100, starting from 0 or upwards.
So what I would like to do i have a color until 40, one until 70, 85, 95, and 100.

Comment: @user1075551 -- You should make that clear in your question.  That makes this a significantly harder problem.